# How to include file from another directory

Tags: php

In the root (www) I have two folders.

In the first folder, "folder1", I put a file called register.php.

In the next folder, "folder2", I put files called header.php and footer.php.

I need to include the header and footer files from folder2 in the register.php file.

How can i do this? I tried to use this include ../folder2/header.php
..but it does not work

Answer (score 18):

On some configurations, adding `./` (current dir) does the trick like this:

```
include './../folder2/header.php';
```

Alternatively, you can specify in terms of document root:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'folder2/header.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'folder2/header.php' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder2/header.php';
```

would work from any directory of the site
it is called `absolute path` and it's the only reliable way to address a file

However, in real it should be something like

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cfg.php';
// some code
include $TPL_HEADER;
```

using a variable, previously defined in `cfg.php`

However, it may fail too. Because you can be just wrong about these paths
And here goes your main problem:

> but it does not work

There is no such thing as "it does not work"
There is always a comprehensive *error message* that tells you what **exactly** doesn't work and what it does instead. You didn't read it yourself, and you didn't post it here to let us show you a **correct path** out of these error messages.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message. It's simply printing the page without the php.

Answer (score 0):

include files should generally be kept outside of the server root.

lets say your setup is;

`www/website1`

and

`www/includes`

Then you php.ini file, or .htaccess file should stipulate that

include_path=www/includes

then from any of your files, in any directory, no matter how far down the trees they go you simply do:

`include 'myfile.php';`

where myfile.php is at www/includes/myfile.php

Then you can stop worrying about these issues

Answer (score 0):

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../folder2/header.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This it is work in my case**

```html
<?php require_once __DIR__."/../filename.php";?>
```

Answer (score -2):

As the PHP manual states [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is "The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file." For this example, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will work just fine but. . . By using the new  ["magic constants"](http://de3.php.net/constants.predefined) provided in >= PHP 5.3, we can make this code a little safer.

Put your includes in a subfolder, and use the magic constant **DIR** to make a reference to the included files. **DIR** returns the directory of the currently executing php file. By using this, you can move your folder containing all your includes anywhere you like in your directory structure, and not need to worry if your includes will still work.

Comment: You completely misunderstood this information. There is nothing "safer" in the `__DIR__` constant and it cannot help to use 
includes anywhere you like. it's just the same as `dirname(__FILE__)` and the same *relative* path, not *absolute*. That a strange delusion I see here on SO very often.

Comment: Thank you so much for you polite response.

Comment: My reason for using __DIR__ instead of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is because if the location of your include files were to change, __DIR__ would still provide a correct path to your includes folder, allowing you to easily use this includes structure on multiple projects in any location. If I used $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includeme.php' I must always have includeme.php in the document root. If I used __DIR__ in the file /www/folder1/includer.php to reference includes in /www/folder1/includes, I could then cut and copy folder1 anywhere i want in the site, or to another site anywhere.

Comment: And you are right, safer was a poor choice of words. My method is more scalable and modular. I hope this clears my point.

Comment: Your logic is broken. if you move '/includeme.php' somewhere, `__DIR__` won't help you either. And if you move a file that contain this include statement, `__DIR__ won't help you but DOCUMENT_ROOT would.